# Github Pull Request Builder not working with DSL plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have hosted a [DummyProject2](https://github.com/codernavi18/DummyProject2) on github and I want to setup a local CI for this using Jenkins. I have setup webhook triggers for everything on github. This is my seed job DSL script.

```
job('upstreamJob') {
    scm {
        git {
            remote {
                github('codernavi18/DummyProject2')
                refspec('+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*')
            }
        }  
    }
    steps {
        shell('echo "This build is triggered from pull request"')
    }
    triggers {
        githubPullRequest {
            useGitHubHooks()
            permitAll()
            autoCloseFailedPullRequests()
            displayBuildErrorsOnDownstreamBuilds()
        }
    }
}
```

When I raise a pull request on the project, my job `upstreamJob` is not getting triggered. What's wrong with my code?

PS : If i used a different plugin `Github Integration Plugin` then my builds are getting triggered properly based on the pull requests. This means my webhooks are fine and connection is also not the issue.

Comment: Did you follow [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) tutorial? I don't think you entered the 'Branch Specifier' config setting.